# Exception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:\\serveraddress\db;create=false

Tags: c#, .net, database, jdbc, derby

I know that this question has been asked many times... BUT it was always referring to JAVA. not this time

1. Code is built in C# using derbyNET.dll (and compiled from .jar to
   .dll derby.dll and derbytools.dll)
2. The same code written in Java (and also compiled in JAVA using javac
   && java...) works properly only if i add before program runs:set
   CLASSPATH=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7\DB-DER~1.0-B\lib\derby.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7\DB-DER~1.0-B\lib\derbytools.jar;
3. code written in C# throws mentioned error. I tried also transform
   this code from java to c# and error was the same.
4. I am pretty sure that issue is caused because C# do not see the
   libraries as driver (derby.dll and derbytools.dll)

Any advice how add this driver to visual studio?

CODE in C#:

```
try{
    DerbyNET derbyDB = new DerbyNET(@"\\serveraddress\sql\db;        create=false");
    if (!derbyDB.openConnection()){
         //Error opening Derby DB
         Console.WriteLine("not connected");
         return;
    }

    DataTable oDT = derbyDB.getRS("SELECT * FROM admin.user_data") as DataTable;
    if (oDT.Columns[0].ColumnName == "Erro"){
        //Read the ** ERRORS ** section below
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        oDT = derbyDB.getRS("SELECT * FROM FROM admin.user_data") as DataTable;
    }
    else if (oDT.Rows.Count == 1 && oDT.Columns.Count == 1){
         //Some error occured
         String strError = derbyDB.getLastError();
         return;
     }

    foreach (DataRow row in oDT.Rows){
       Console.WriteLine("---ROW---");
       foreach (var item in row.ItemArray){
           Console.Write("Item: ");
           Console.WriteLine(item);
       }
    }
  derbyDB.closeConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

CODE in JAVA:

```
try{  
     {    
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:\\\\serveraddress\\sql\\db;create=false");
       Statement sta = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ADMIN.USER_DATA");
       java.lang.System.@out.println("ADMIN.USER_DATA: ");
      while (res.next()){
         java.lang.System.@out.println("  " + res.getString("USERID") + ", " + res.getString("PASSWORD") + ", " + res.getString("FIRST_NAME") + ", " + res.getString("LAST_NAME") +
                            ", " + res.getString("EMAIL"));
     }
      res.close();
      sta.close();
      con.close();
     }
 }
 catch (System.Exception e){
      {
        java.lang.System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make what (in Java terms) we'd call an **embedded** connection? Or are you trying to make what (in Java terms) we'd call a **client-server** connection? That is, is there a Derby Network Server on the other end of your connection?

Comment: In Java terms i have everything worked fine. Data is being pulled from db. Issue is with C# code, always throws no suitable driver. In Java perspective before I run the code I am setting class path(with two mentioned libs) then javac && Java mycode.java - this is working.

Comment: And yes, at the end is Apache derby database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. 
1) two libraries derbytools.jar and derby.jar have to be compiled via ikvmc to .dll and add as reference
2) need to add NuGet package "IKVM.OpenJDK.Jdbc and IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
3) current code is (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using java.sql;
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
Connection derbyConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:\\\\serveraddress\\directory\\sql\\db;create=false");
Statement sta = derbyConn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
java.lang.System.@out.println("tablename: ");
            while (res.next())
            {

                java.lang.System.@out.println("  " + res.getString("1stColumn") + ", " + res.getString("2ndColumn"));
            }
            res.close()
            sta.close();
            derbyConn.close();
```